# How to handle contact request in telegram-bot-sdk using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am using https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk to develop a bot in my Laravel project. I have successfully requested contact using the Reply Keyboard Markup. The problem is I couldn't process the contact further. I need help on how to use the phone number I requested for further processes.

This is the code I am using now,

```php
public function requestContact() 
{
    $btn = Keyboard::button([
        'text' => 'Share my phone number',
        'request_contact' => true
    ]);
    $keyboard = Keyboard::make([
        'keyboard' => [[$btn]],
        'resize_keyboard' => true,
        'one_time_keyboard' => true
    ]);
    Telegram::sendMessage([
        'chat_id' => $this->chat_id,
        'text' => 'I need your contact to get your ID. Please click the Share Contact button below.',
        'reply_markup' => $keyboard
    ]);ref
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First** : 
You don't need "Share contact" to get user ID that you wrote here :

> 'text' => 'I need your contact to get your ID. Please click the Share Contact button below.'

**Second** :
 I shared my contact via one of my bots and the Telegram sent this response for me :

```
 {
   "ok": true,
   "result": [{
     "update_id": 751829617,
     "message": {
       "message_id": 5971,
       "from": {
         "id": 223110107,
         "is_bot": false,
         "first_name": "\u011e\u0105me",
         "last_name": "\u01fever!",
         "username": "GameO7er",
         "language_code": "en"
       },
       "chat": {
         "id": 223110107,
         "first_name": "\u011e\u0105me",
         "last_name": "\u01fever!",
         "username": "GameO7er",
         "type": "private"
       },
       "date": 1568724975,
       "contact": {
         "phone_number": "+1*******88",
         "first_name": ".",
         "user_id": 223110107
       }
     }
   }]
 }
```

so as you can see in the above example in JSON format , you can do something like this:

`TelegramResponse->message->contact->phone_number`

above code is just a sample and it doesn't work. but you can lookup for the `phone_number` [here](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/search?q=phone_number&unscoped_q=phone_number)